# How to use wildcard filter url with a list webpart

Tags: 2013, list, web-part, filter, url

So I've been using url to create custom filters. Users can so customize their filter trough a form and with javascript i'm updating the url so the list webpart is filtered. The only problem is in a page with a list web part component multi values seems to not work. I can only search for exact values.

I tried multivalues in the list view page (allitems.aspx) and it works there: For example i can write something like : `?filtername=City&FilterMultiValue=*land*` And it will filter the column "City" with values CONTAINING land anywhere in sentence. And it works there (on the allitems.aspx page).

To make the url filter on a basic page (where you can add webparts) you have to add the list and then you add to the url `#InplviewHashWEBPARTIDOFTHELIST?FILTERS`

So far i can easily set a filter but i can only do it with FilterValue, `FilterField1=City&FilterValue1=land`And this will only find values that are the exact word "land". If i try the multivalue filter i can use on the allitems.aspx page, it won't work with the webpart. So far I don't know how to make it work there.

Any ideas?

I use html form webpart and created a custom form that sets the url once you click on the search button. I use this method because with webpart connections you can only set filter on one single column.